# Confirm Deletion not found

Tags: users

I need to delete user.

When go to `wp-admin/users.php` and click to delete, and redirect to delete page,

I cannot see Confirm Deletion.

How can delete user ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to select either of option button: "Delete all content" or "Attribute all content to:" then "Confirm Deletion" button will get enabled.

If you are not able to see the button itself then some plugin css must be hiding it. So please try deactivating plugins one by one and check if you can see the button.

Comment: i deactivating all plugin and samee thing